# Upload multipart blob with storage class RRS

Tags: amazon-s3, jclouds

Right now jcloud provides the ability to upload a blob in aws s3 storage with the following two storage classes : **STANDARD** and **RRS**. As I see there is the case when multipart upload is performed and RRS is selected as a storage class the blob will be uploaded with the default storage class i.e STANDARD. 
For example:

```
blobStore.putBlob(null,blob,storageClass(ObjectMetadata.StorageClass.REDUCED_REDUNDANCY).multipart())
```

This will be uploaded with STANDARD storage class.
Is there a reason to ignore selected storage class when multipart is performed?
Why does everything different than  RRS is considered to be STANDARD? If I select STANDARD_IA the storage class in use will be again STANDARD.

EDIT:
This is the code which is executed when blob is uploaded. As you can see using multipart excludes RRS storage class.

```
@Override
public String putBlob(String container, Blob blob, PutOptions options) {
    if (options.isMultipart()) {
        return putMultipartBlob(container, blob, options);
    } else if ((options instanceof AWSS3PutOptions) &&
            (((AWSS3PutOptions) options).getStorageClass() == REDUCED_REDUNDANCY)) {
        return putBlobWithReducedRedundancy(container, blob);
    } else {
        return super.putBlob(container, blob, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jclouds 2.1.0 will improve support for storage classes in S3 and add support to the portable abstraction.  Can you test against 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT and report any issues against [JCLOUDS-1337](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-1337)?

Comment: So, impossibility to use RSS with multipart is not intentional?  I checked out 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT and from what I see there is no RSS storage class support. It defaults to STANDARD

Comment: The portable abstraction cannot express REDUCED_REDUNDANCY since no other providers support this.  You can, however, use the provider level S3Client.  You will have to drive the multipart interaction yourself via initiateMultipartUpload (setting ObjectMetadata StorageClass), uploadPart, and completeMultipartUpload.